# Heredoc ending tag is displayed on browser

Tags: php, tags, heredoc

I am trying to recursively print some html code using heredoc syntax but the php    code gets displayed as a comment.

```
<?php

$amount = 9;
function loadpostings($i) { 
    if ($i == $amount) return; 
    $idnum = intostring($i); 


    $postingblock = <<<BLOCK
    <div class="posting" id="posting$idnum">
    <img class="uparrow" id="up$idnum" src="pics/up.jpeg">
    <img class="downarrow" id="down$idnum" src="pics/down.jpeg">
    <dt class="headline" id="headline$idnum"> </dt> 
    <dd class="body" id="body$idnum"></dd>
    </div>
BLOCK; 
    echo $idnum; 
    $i++;
    loadpostings($i);
}
 loadpostings(0);
```

The browser displays:

```
BLOCK; echo $idnum; $i++; loadpostings($i); } loadpostings(0);
```

Comment: start or close **PHP** tag properly

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces before the ending `BLOCK;`

Comment: Sorry I havent posted much here, the block has no space in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me perfectly. I found a space before and after `BLOCK;` just removed it and working!

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't seem to be working for me. Could it be my php settings?

Comment: try a simple example in an empty php file. This would clear your doubt!